# Stage not resizing on orientation change

Tags: resize, orientation, kineticjs, stage

Am creating an image editor library with the support of KinetiJS.

In my html,

```
    <div id="editorarea" class="fill">
        <div id="imageContainerDiv" class="imageContainerDiv" >
        <div>....</div>
        <div>....</div>
        <div id='rotateouterDiv' class='rotateouterDiv' >
            <textarea placeholder='Enter You Text here' id='inputField' name='graffiti' class='textContainerMob'></textarea>
        </div>
        <div id='imageContainer'></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then creating a stage

```
_kineticStage = new editor._Stage({
    container : 'imageContainer',
    width : $('#editorarea').width(),
    height : $('#editorarea').height()
});

Kinetic.Util.extend(editor._Stage, Kinetic.Stage);
```

And adding an image,

```
_kineticImage = new editor._Image({
    x : 0,
    image : img,
    y : 0,
    draggable : true,
});
layer.add(_kineticImage);
```

The CSS applied is,

```
#editorarea {
    width: 100%;
    height: 80%;
    margin-top: .1%;

    min-height: 70%%;
    display: block;
    border-width: 2px;
    border-style: solid;
}

.fill {
    min-height: 85%;
    height: 90%;
}

.imageContainerDiv {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-color: #FFF;
    display: block;
    background-image: url(../images/back_pattern.png);
    background-repeat: repeat;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

The `textarea` should be on the top of the image. In this case, I placed that div containing the `textarea` using the `@media` queries, for supporting different screen size and orientation.

The issue occurs when following the steps: load the page in portrait, then change the device orientation to landscape. Then the position of `textarea` is not correct. This is because the kinetic stage is not properly resizing on orientation change (only the area with image).

Can anyone help me to resize it properly? This should work in touch devices.

Thanks...